# Calculate the angle $x$, no other information was given

Tags: triangles, angle, polygons

I tried to solve this question, looked at this for very long and still was not able to find a solution. Can anybody here help me. This question was asked by our teacher and I have no information from where he got it.
[[image: this is the image]]

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I tried to calculate all the interior angles. Got maximum values but the biggest triangle in the middle was having two unknown still giving equation (x + y(let) = 90).

Comment: can you solve it when you draw it using a protractor and a ruler?

Comment: Probably but he asked us to do this using geometry laws only rather than construction. And also side length is unknown

Comment: Let's say $CE$ is $1$, then 
$$BE = \tan 80^\circ,\quad DE = \tan 60^\circ \quad\text{ and } AE = DE \tan 70^\circ$$
This implies $x = \tan^{-1}\frac{AE}{BE}  = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan 60^\circ \tan 70^\circ}{\tan 80^\circ}\right) = 40^\circ$.
Since this angle is so simple, I suspect there is a more geometry way to get this but I fail to see it at this moment.

Comment: what if you assume that the length of CD is 1. Can you calculate $x$? or isn't it allowed, too?

Comment: The correct answer as out teacher said is 40. But he told us to solve only by angle/geometry laws rather than trigonometry. Thanks for this solution though.

Comment: I notice $AB = AD$ and $BC = AC$, not sure whether that helps or not...

Comment: @achillehui I don't believe that AB=AD, because then x=70 and BE=DE

Comment: @miracle173 oops, should be $AB = BD$.

Comment: @achillehui  but if $AB=BD$ then $\angle (BAD)=\angle(BDA)=70$, so $\angle(BAE)=\angle(BAD)-\angle(EAD)=70-20=50$, and $x=40$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\tan x = &\frac{AE}{BE}
=\frac{AE}{DE}\cdot \frac{CE}{BE}\cdot \frac{DE}{CE} 
=\tan70\tan80\tan60\\
=&\frac{\sin70\cos80\sin60}{\cos40\sin40\cos70 }
=\frac{\sin70(\sin40-\sin20)}{\cos40(\cos20+\cos120) }
=\frac{\sin70\sin40-\frac12 \sin40}{\cos40(\sin70-\frac12) }\\
=& \frac{\sin40}{\cos40 }=\tan40\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the circumcenter of triangle $BCD$. Then $\angle BEC = 2\angle BDC = 60^\circ$ and additionally $EB=EC$, hence $EBC$ is equilateral. Also note that $\angle CAD = 20^\circ =2\angle CBD =\angle CED$, hence $EADC$ is cyclic. Moreover, $\angle EDB =90^\circ -\frac 12 \angle BED = 90^\circ -\frac 12 80^\circ = 50^\circ$, so $\angle ADE =\angle ADB -\angle EDB =70^\circ -50^\circ =20^\circ =\angle CED$. It follows that $EC \parallel AD$. So $EADC$ is a cyclic trapezoid, hence it is isosceles and now we see that our picture is symmetric with respect to perpendicular bisector of $CE$. It is easy to calculate now that $\angle DBA = 40^\circ$.
[image]